# How to clear cache on page loading magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cache, controllers, full-page-cache, block-cache

I need to flush cache when a controller is loaded. This is mandatory for me because some function works only when cache is cleared. I Hope will get help.

Comment: it  is not good idea to flush cache on controller hit.Can u  please tell which function is not working when cache is enabled?

Comment: I need to show a value from database. When db is updated the value in frontend is not updating. It is updating when cache is flushed alone.

Comment: Can u please share the code which you have tried and where you face the issues?

Comment: $suser_id = $this->getCustomerId();
    $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection'); 
    $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT money  FROM `total_cashback` WHERE `user_id` = '$suser_id'  ";
    $result = $connection->fetchall($sql);
     @$total = $result['0']; 
    $totalmoney = $total['money'];
    return $totalmoney;

Comment: In this code I'm getting table value but when table value is updated it is not updating in frontend until cache clearence

Answer (score 2):

**1. Define constructor – pass Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface and Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool to your file’s constructor as defined below :**

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
}
```

**2. Now add following code to the method where you want clear/flush cache**

```
$types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

Comment: I used this in block function but cache is not cleaned when page is reloaded or loaded